# Copying and pasting only cells with values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter two columns: one with date and the other with values (10 and below).

I'm trying to copy the filtered values into a different sheet but it seems the code copies the entire column instead of just the visible values. When pasting it shows an error "paste area isn't the same size". How can I fix this?

Below is my code:

```
LastRow = btsvoice.Range("J" & btsvoice.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = btsvoice.Range("J2:J" & LastRow)

' filter and delete all but header row
With rng
    For Each lo In btsvoice.ListObjects
        lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Next lo

    On Error Resume Next
        .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Date - 3
        .AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:="<11"
    On Error GoTo 0

    btsvoice.Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    btsdata.Range("A5:A14").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With
```

Comment: It will help if you can show a sample. Anyhow... you are copying `"I:I"` visible values (so a column) in `"A5:A14"` that is a range so it is not possible. You can select the values on column I from the first one to the last visible and copy on A5, but as soon as you are limiting the number of  rows, you will get that error.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Exactly, I'm rying to copy the values in column I from the first one to the last visible and copy to A5. That's what Im having trouble with. It will always be 10 values copied. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead to use `I:I` go for `I1:I & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`. If it is not I1, just replace...

Comment: You can just paste to range `range("A5")`

Comment: Since you already set your rng for column J all you had to do was change  `Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` to `rng.Offset(-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
'Variables
sheet1row1 = 1 'One cell above the start row number for the list of data you are interested in
sheet1column1 = 10 'The 1st column number of the data you are interested in
sheet1column2 = 35 'The 2nd column number of the data you are interested in

sheet2row1 = 1 'The row number on sheet 2 where the 1st set of data is to be displayed
sheet2row2 = 1 'The row number on sheet 2 where the 2nd set of data is to be displayed
sheet2column1 = 1 'The column number on sheet 2 for the 1st set of data
sheet2column2 = 2 'The column number on sheet 2 for the 2nd set of data

lastline = 100 'What ever the row value is of your last entry

Do
    'Increment the number of the cell to look at
    sheet1row1 = sheet1row1 + 1
    'Read the contents of the cell in the first column you are interested in
    cellvalue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sheet1row1, sheet1column1).Value
    'Check if the value in the cell meets your required value
    If cellvalue >= Date - 3 Then
        'It meets your requirements so paste it to the second sheet
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(sheet2row1, sheet2column1).Value = cellvalue
        'Increment the paste position of the second sheet
        sheet2row1 = sheet2row1 + 1
    End If
    'Read the contents of the cell in the next column you are interested in
    cellvalue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sheet1row1, sheet1column2).Value
    'Check if the value in the cell meets your required value
    If cellvalue < 11 Then
        'It meets your requirements so paste it to the second sheet
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(sheet2row2, sheet2column2).Value = cellvalue
        'Increment the paste position of the second sheet
        sheet2row2 = sheet2row2 + 1
    End If
Loop Until sheet1row1 > lastline
```

Comment: Using a filter would be better than looping through each row. The OP has the right idea using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`